# NoSQL database design - repeatable data

Tags: database-design, nosql

I'm learning nosql and trying to understand how would a database design will look like for a movie database website, for example? This is very confusing for me, because I can't wrap my head around the fact I'm duplicating so many information. I'll give you an example(perhaps I didn't get it right and you could correct me):

So, if I have a movie:

```
{
    "title": "Interstellar",
    "director": ...
    ...
    "genre": [
        "Comedy", "Action", ...
    ],
    "actors": [
        {
            "name": ...
            ...
        },
        {
            "name": ...
            ...
        },
    ],
}
```

I will have lots of same "genre" and "actors" between movies. It doesn't seem to be logical... and if I have another repeatable things such as "categories", for example? And what if I want to link between user and movies? I mean, do you see what am I talking about? Please clarify how(and why) this should be implemented in nosql.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: We can't tell you what design is appropriate without a specification.  Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me, the magic about noSQL is about deciding how much redundancy you want. Deciding when is it better to store a full object or just a pointer to another object in other collection is just matter of what you want to do.

For example, if you wanted to store information about movies and the actors that participated in them, then you could use something like this:

```
{
    movies: [
    {
        name: ...
        genres: ...
        rating: ...
        actors: [ id-actor1, id-actor2, id-actor3]
    }, 
    { 
        name: ...
        genres: ...,
        rating: ...,
        actors: [id-actor2, id-actor4]
    },
    { other bunch of actors }
    ],
    actors: [
    {
        id: id-actor1,
        name: John McActor,
        favorite_food: Tacos
    },
    {
        id: id-actor2,
        name: Jenny McActress,
        favorite_food: Pizza
    },
    { other bunch of actors }
    ]
}
```

That way you don't have to store the information about the actors in every movie, but just an identifier to filter when you need the information. This way the actors are not stored in every single movie, but only are referenced and you can reduce the DB size by a lot.

There is a bunch of different ways you could do this, by increasing or reducing redundancy, but it ultimately depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: As a side note, you dont HAVE to use noSQL. When most of the data is very closely related, its better to use SQL to work with the relations in your favor. When you just need a simple design and the data is less connected, it will be easier to use noSQL.